# Can TCP client that keeps sending packets below MTU be assumed as malicious?

Tags: linux, tcp, epoll

I am working with a custom TCP protocol that has length-prefixed packet frames with data.
The frames can go up to a few MBs.
A proper and legitimate client, prepares the frame into a buffer first and then writes that buffer with `write(...)` syscall.

One of the DoS scenarios in this case is a malicious client which will keep sending really small chunks of the frame, as that is forcing the application to work on cumulating the data with memory copies each time.
I want to limit the maximum number of data cumulations before client is disconnected as malicious - one epoll notification that data can be read would be one cumulation(so Linux would usually buffer the data to some degree).
Is it OK to assume that number based on connection MTU(like 1480 bytes?) - as a legit client should keep sending large frames with max MTU size or very close to it?

So for example: if we received a packet length prefix saying 2MB, and the client follows with packets of 10 bytes each instead of near-MTU packets, we may assume the client is malicious.

Answer (score 0):

On a TCP socket all record boundaries such as sendto(2) or write(2) disappear at the receiving end; network traffic is just a continuous stream of octets.  Any data structure, such as record boundaries, are just a convention agreed to by the sender and the receiver.  So from a TCP perspective, no, this question is not even possible.

As far a protocol design is concerned, no, near-MTU records are not evil and are actually a *good* idea because it maximizes network traffic while minimizes network overhead.

Is this homework?

Comment: I am not sure you understood me right - I said near-MTU records are good, and not evil. So the other way around.

Comment: This is not homework. This is a production app that I want to protect against a packet fragmentation DoS scenario while avoiding false positives and disconnecting legitimate clients.

Answer (score 0):

This fully depends on the application protocol.

If it is a protocol which is designed for **high throughput** (like downloads) than TCP should be used with large packets near the MTU and lots of small packets instead of a single should be considered suboptimal. If this is due to a bad implementation of the protocol or due some attacker is another matter though, but the protocol specification might give hints on how the protocol should be implemented.

If the protocol is instead designed for **low latency** (like interactive protocols) then many small packets can be pretty normal.

Comment: as I mentioned about `length-prefixed packet frames with data`, that means that the data itself isn't of any use until the full(for example 5MB) frame has been received, and can be further processed. and so any latency tweaks based on smaller MTU would not be suitable.

Comment: if the packet length header says the data is below MTU, then of course I would expect next packet to be smaller than the MTU and that would be completely fine

Comment: @underflow: just because *"The frames can go up to a few MBs"* does not mean that all frames will be a few MB, i.e. this specification does not prohibit small frames. Like I said, the difference is on what the protocol is designed for and how you expect the client to be  implemented. It would probably the best to not only assume but to make explicit requirements on the client in your specification, specifically that [NAGLE algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) should be kept enabled.

Comment: "does not mean that all frames will be few MBs" - as I said, this is something known as soon as length prefix has arrived and further decisions can be based on that